# IFTTT Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, webhooks, ifttt

I'm trying to create a `'POST'` request to the IFTTT webhook service.
Using:

```
function deleteRow(ID){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/delete_row/with/key/{key}',
    data: '{"value":"'+ID+'"}',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
}
```

Response:

```
Failed to load https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/delete_row/with/key/{key}: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{mysite}' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Whats wrong with my request?

Comment: What is `{key}` supposed to be in the url? And where should it come from in the javascript?

Comment: Key is my personal key which I received from IFTTT.

Comment: OK. Then that API is not CORS enabled. Check if it serves JSONP, or requires special params in url for ajax or use a proxy on your server to communicate with the remote api. Not all API's are ajax accessible, often to protect credentials being put in browser

Comment: Tried JSONP and solved my problem

Comment: @George can you please tell me how did you solve it with `JSONP`? Feel free to answer your own question... Thanks!